# spring "propdeps-plugin" no longer working

Tags: spring, build.gradle

I used to be able to download one of my plugin dependencies using Gradle, but it has now stopped functioning.

Anyone utilising or familiar with the problem's root cause ?

[Maven Dependency Link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.build.gradle/propdeps-plugin/0.0.7)

```
Error which i'm getting:

problem occurred configuring root project 'Api-prog'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not download propdeps-plugin.jar (org.springframework.build.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.7)
      > Could not get resource 'https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/org/springframework/build/gradle/propdeps-plugin/0.0.7/propdeps-plugin-0.0.7.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/org/springframework/build/gradle/propdeps-plugin/0.0.7/propdeps-plugin-0.0.7.jar'. Received status code 401 from server: 


Here is my gradle setting and error


buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.build.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.7"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case, as you already specified the version `io.spring.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.9.RELEASE`:

1. Change the Spring repository URL to `https://repo.spring.io/plugins-snapshot`.
2. Change the `propdeps` version to `io.spring.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.8-SNAPSHOT`.

Example `build.gradle` blocks:

```
    repositories {        
      maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/plugins-snapshot" }        
    }
    
    // ...
    
    dependencies {
       classpath "io.spring.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.8-SNAPSHOT"
    }
```

Comment: Hi @ahmed, thanks for your help. Could you tell me why this change is required?

Comment: @ankit as described by Ilian spring.io does not serve anymore releases and should be downloaded from maven central.
https://spring.io/blog/2022/12/14/notice-of-permissions-changes-to-repo-spring-io-january-2023

Answer (score 0):

I am currently experiencing the same issue since Friday. Looking into it now it seems that spring.io does now serve release versions anymore and they should be downloaded from Maven Central:

https://spring.io/blog/2022/12/14/notice-of-permissions-changes-to-repo-spring-io-january-2023

Edit:

I am using Maven and I had to change my repository (old url used to be `https://repo.spring.io/release/`) to this:

```
    <repository>
        <id>springio-release</id>
        <name>Spring Releases</name>
        <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
```

This has solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous access to release branch restricted now by Spring.

Replace

```
maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/" }
```

With

```
maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/plugins-snapshot" }
```